# Determining a closed-form solution for the following sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series

I have the following summation:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\left(6in + n(8n+2)\right).$$
Evaluating I get
\begin{align*}
6n\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right) + n(8n+2) = 3n(n(n+1)) + n(8n+2)\\
&=3n^2(n+1) + n(8n+2)\\
&=3n^3 + 3n^2 + 8n^2 + 2n\\
&=3n^3 + 11n^2 + 2n.
\end{align*}

Is this correct?

Comment: Are you starting with $$\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}6in\right)+n(8n+2)$$ or $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(6in+n(8n+2)\right)?$$

Comment: the second one.

Comment: I know that what you want is the value of the sum, but isn't $\sum_{i=0}^n\left(6in + n(8n+2)\right)$ a closed form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first step is wrong.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} (6in + n(8n+2)) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (6in) + \sum_{i=0}^{n} n(8n+2)$$

You wrote

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} (6in) = 6n \sum_{i=0}^{n} i =  6n^2(n+1)/2$$

but missed this one:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} n(8n+2) = n(8n+2) \sum_{i=0}^n 1 =  n(n+1)(8n+2)$$

and wrote

$$n(8n+2)$$

instead.

Comment: in the second summation, are you adding n+1 because the index starts at 0 and not 1?

Comment: @kry: Yes, exactly! You are adding n+1 times.

Comment: but when evaluating the first summation, it does not need to be multiplied by (n+1) because you are plugging in for i directly?

Comment: @Kry: I have edited the answer to clarify it a bit. Since $n$ is independent of $i$, you can take it out of the $\sum$.

Comment: thanks! that cleared it up